# How to interpret PCA results in supervised ML

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca, supervised-learning

So I have a data set of 700 texts annotated by difficulty levels. Each text has 150 features:

```
    feature_names = ['F1','F2','F3'...] shape (1, 150)
    features_x = ['0.1','0,765', '0.543'...] shape (700, 150)
    correct_answers_y = ['1','2','4'...] shape (1,700)
```

I want to use PCA to find out the most informative sets of features, something like:

```
    Component1 = 0,76*F1+0.11*F4-0.22*F7
```

How can I do so? The code from sklearn user gide have some numbers as output, but I don`t understand how to unterpret them.

```
    fit_xy = pca.fit(features_x,correct_answers_y)
    array([  4.01783322e-01,   1.98421989e-01,  3.08468655e-01,
     4.28813755e-02, ...])
```

Comment: This is the code used to get the original features back from transformed data. This can help you:- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/decomposition/base.py#L136

Comment: `pca.fit()` [gets only one argument (X)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html#sklearn.decomposition.PCA.fit); PCA is an *unsupervised* technique for data transformation, and it does not take into account the labels. The `correct_answers_y` argument in your `fit_xy` is simply ignored.

Comment: PCA is usually for dimensionality reduction.  The labels are never used because it is an unsupervised algorithm.  If you want to take the labels into account, consider using Linear Discriminant Analysis: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html

Answer (score -1):

Not sure where that array comes from, but it looks like the output of `explained_variance_` or `explained_variance_ratio_` attributes. They are as they say; explained variance and explained variance ratio compared to your data. Usually when doing a PCA you're defining a minimum of ratio of variance you want to keep from the data.

Lets say you want to keep at least 90% of the variance in your data. Here's code to find how many principle components (`n_components` parameter in PCA) you need:

```
    pca_cumsum = pca.explained_variance_ratio_.cumsum()
    pca_cumsum
    >> np.array([.54, .79, .89, .91, .97, .99, 1])
    np.argmax(pca_cumsum >= 0.9)
    >> 3
```

And as desertnaut said; labels will be ignored, as it is not used in PCA.